# Android Studio error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick)

Tags: java, android

I'm coding a running/fitness application that tracks running distance. It appears fine in Android Studio but there are some errors when running the application. Here is the code:

```
     public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public static final String TAG = "FitnessApp";
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
public LatLng latLng, latLngStart;
public Pair pair;
Handler Handler = new Handler();
private long startTime, elapsedTime;
private final int REFRESH_RATE = 100;
private String hours, minutes, seconds;
private long secs, mins, hrs;
private boolean stopped = false;
public int dist;
public int Speed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    latLng = new LatLng (1.3263, 103.8026);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}

public LatLng handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude,currentLongitude);
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("You are here!");
    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    return latLng;
}

public void startClick(View view) {
    showStopButton();
    if(stopped){
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime;
    }
    else{
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    Handler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
    Handler.postDelayed(startTimer, 0);
    h1.removeCallbacks(startCalorieTracker);
    h1.postDelayed(startCalorieTracker,0);
    latLngStart = new LatLng (latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude);
}

public void stopClick(View view) {
    Double lat1 = latLngStart.latitude;
    Double lon1 = latLngStart.longitude;
    Double lat2 = latLng.latitude;
    Double lon2 = latLng.longitude;
    getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
    hideStopButton();
    Handler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
    h1.removeCallbacks(startCalorieTracker);
    stopped = true;
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance)).setText(dist);
    if (hrs > 0 || mins > 0 || secs >0) {
        Speed = dist/(Integer.parseInt(hours)+(Integer.parseInt(minutes)/60)+(Integer.parseInt(seconds)/3600));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.speed)).setText(Speed + "km/h");
    }
    else {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.speed)).setText("0 km/h");
    }
}

public void resetClick(View view) {
    stopped = false;
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.time)).setText("00:00:00");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance)).setText("0 km");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.speed)).setText("0 km/h");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.calories)).setText("0 Cal");
}

public int getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
    double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
    double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB - lonA)) +
            (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
    double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
    double dist = ang * 6371;
    return (int) dist;
}

private void showStopButton(){
    findViewById(R.id.buttonStart).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonReset).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonStop).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void hideStopButton(){
    findViewById(R.id.buttonStart).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonReset).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonStop).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

//Timer
private Runnable startTimer = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        updateTimer(elapsedTime);
        Handler.postDelayed(this,REFRESH_RATE);
    }
};

private void updateTimer (float time){
    secs = (long)(time/1000);
    mins = (long)((time/1000)/60);
    hrs = (long)(((time/1000)/60)/60);

    secs = secs % 60;
    seconds=String.valueOf(secs);
    if(secs == 0){
        seconds = "00";
    }
    if(secs <10 && secs > 0){
        seconds = "0"+seconds;
    }

    mins = mins % 60;
    minutes=String.valueOf(mins);
    if(mins == 0){
        minutes = "00";
    }
    if(mins <10 && mins > 0){
        minutes = "0"+minutes;
    }

    hours=String.valueOf(hrs);
    if(hrs == 0){
        hours = "00";
    }
    if(hrs <10 && hrs > 0){
        hours = "0"+hours;
    }

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.time)).setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
}

public Handler h1= new Handler ();
public Runnable startCalorieTracker = new Runnable () {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        h1.postDelayed(this, REFRESH_RATE);
        int CaloriesBurnt = dist*85;
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.calories)).setText(CaloriesBurnt + "Cal");
    }
};
```

The errors I get:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: rainbow.com.fitnessapp3, PID: 3268
                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
                                                                       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)
                                                                       at rainbow.com.fitnessapp3.MapsActivity.stopClick(MapsActivity.java:175)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I think the problem is with the following lines of code:

```
public void startClick(View view) {
    showStopButton();
    if(stopped){
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime;
    }
    else{
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    Handler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
    Handler.postDelayed(startTimer, 0);
    h1.removeCallbacks(startCalorieTracker);
    h1.postDelayed(startCalorieTracker,0);
    latLngStart = new LatLng (latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude);
}

public void stopClick(View view) {
    Double lat1 = latLngStart.latitude;
    Double lon1 = latLngStart.longitude;
    Double lat2 = latLng.latitude;
    Double lon2 = latLng.longitude;
    getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
    hideStopButton();
    Handler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
    h1.removeCallbacks(startCalorieTracker);
    stopped = true;
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance)).setText(dist);
    if (hrs > 0 || mins > 0 || secs >0) {
        Speed = dist/(Integer.parseInt(hours)+(Integer.parseInt(minutes)/60)+(Integer.parseInt(seconds)/3600));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.speed)).setText(Speed + "km/h");
    }
    else {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.speed)).setText("0 km/h");
    }
}
```

Comment: just as hint, a void method can't return even one value....

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

public **void** handleNewLocation(Location location)

Your method is void, and as such, doesn't return any value when executed.

The simplest solution would be to use the **Pair** object, to return two values, like this:

```
public Pair<String, String> handleNewLocation(Location location){
//do your thing here
[...]
Pair<String, String> pair = new Pair<>();
pair.first = Double.toString(currentLatitude);
pair.second = Double.toString(currentLongitude);
return pair;
}
```

And then, when you need to use that method, use it like:

```
Pair pair = handleNewLocation(Location location);
String firstValue = pair.first; //THIS IS THE FIRST VALUE
String secondValue = pair.second; //THIS IS THE SECOND VALUE
```

The other way to do this is to create a custom object, a "POJO", that would hold your values. Look up on how to create a POJO, it is interesting, useful, and good to know if you want to get into Java programming.

Also note that you shouldn't make your methods "public" unless you need to. If you're using the method only in the class it is written in, you can make it "private". This is a good practice to do, to ensure that your application is safe and protected.